# How to load html using jquery into a TinyMCE textarea

Tags: jquery, tinymce, textarea

I've a textarea that uses TinyMCE as a WYSIWYG.
Once that this textarea is loaded I want that, clicking a button "Edit" some html code that I  bring with AJAX jquery is loaded in that textarea.

I want to insert this html code `<p>hello</p>`

Original textarea source

```
<textarea name="corpo" id="input_corpo">Text Here</textarea>
```

JQUERY Script that brings the HTML. In this way it updates only the textarea (which is hidden  while TinyMCE is in action)

```
$.get("hello.html", 
        function(content){ $("#input_corpo").text(content);});
     return false;});
```

Neither in this way below it works. I tryed to update the body of the iframe that generates TinyMCE

```
$.get("hello.html", 
    function(content){ $("body#tinymce").text(content);});
return false;});
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could try with the [setContent](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:API/tinymce.Editor/setContent) function:

```
$.get("hello.html", function(content) { 
    // if you have one tinyMCE box on the page:
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content);
});
```

or even shorter:

```
$.get("hello.html", tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly I was searching for.

Comment: Really curious to hear an answer to mrN's question. How can one target a specific editor on the page?

Comment: If you have more than one editor per page: tinyMCE.get('my_editor').setContent(data);

Answer (score 2):

Using the jQuery version of tinyMCE with jQuery plugin you could use this

```
$.get("hello.html", function(content) { 
    $('#input-corpo').html(content);
});
```