# How to load a html file into a textbox?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to creating a html text editor in asp.net, for that i have kept a textarea for the user to edit the html. My requirement is that, i need to load a default page with basic things in the text area when the page loads.

Comment: what is preventing you from doing this? what are you struggling with?

Comment: how can i load a html file content in to a text box

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use TinyMCE and integrate it into asp.net

More information can be found here:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/RichTextBox-Example-using-Free-TinyMCE-Editor-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: @Venkhatesh There is an answer to that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582251/how-to-load-html-using-jquery-into-a-tinymce-textarea

Comment: If you have an actual ".html" file, and you want to load it's contents to the textarea, I suggest you do it with php file_get_contents (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). After the content is loaded, you initialize tinymce fot that textarea...

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to you use www.daniweb.com..this will be get better idea or go to below link

[How to load the contents in the text file or the html codes in a html-file to a textarea by browsing it first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226971/how-to-load-the-contents-in-the-text-file-or-the-html-codes-in-a-html-file-to-a)